# Can we upgrade solr in DSE(DataStax Enterprise )?

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql

Currently I am using *[DSE (DataStax Enterprise)](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise)* which contain `solr 4.6` but I want to upgrade it from `solr 4.6` to  `solr 4.10`.

So Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSE Search ships with a custom lucene-solr build, so you can't drop in another version. We're working on upgrading our custom lucene-solr implementation to 4.10 for upcoming DSE releases.